# Как экранировать \n в строке при этом не выводить его?

Tags: python

```
a = 'Строка\\nСтрока 2'

'Строка\nСтрока 2' # вывод
```

Можно ли убрать \n с помощью экранирования?
При этом

```
b = 'Строка\
Строка 2'
'СтрокаСтрока 2' # выводит нормально
```

Почему во втором случае перенос убирается полностью, а в пером остается в строке?

Comment: Не совсем понятны ваши намерения. Если перенос вам не нужен, может лучше тогда удалить его а не пытаться экранировать?

Comment: что нужно вывести в первом случае?

Answer (score 2):

В втором случае в строке нет переноса. А в первом случае экранируется символ `\`, а буква `n` остается самой обычной буквой.

Comment: Не так написал, имелся в виду этот случай `'''23145\n2525'''`
Как тут убрать перенос?

Comment: вам такое нужно b = a.replace("\n", " ")  ?

Comment: При этом надо чтоб \n полностью убрался как в этом случае `'''23145\
2525'''`
после слеша имеется в виду перенос

Comment: Про реплейс я знаю, меня интересует механизм работы экранирования в данных двух случаях.

Comment: я же написал - во втором случае нет никакого экранирования и переноса. В первом случае экранируется символ \

Comment: ок тогда почему `23145
2525` при переносе потом можно заменить \n в строке? Т.е. \n ставится при переносе которое как раз и экранирует стоящий перед ним \
Поэтому и спрашиваю почему если у меня уже есть \n такого не происходит?

Comment: в последнем комментарии ничего не понятно

Comment: Тогда так, питон после слеша в строке при переносе `23145\ 2525` автоматически вставляет \n. Вопрос, почему когда \n в строке уже есть `'''23145\\n2525'''` и перед ним слеш стоит, то он выводится и не исчезает как в первом случае?

Comment: ДА ПОТОМУ ЧТО В СЛУЧАЕ ``\\n`` ПЕРВЫМ СИМВОЛОМ ``\`` ЭКРАНИРУЕТСЯ ВТОРОЙ СИМВОЛ ``\``, а не ``\n`` целиком. Буква n  остается самой обычной буквой n и печатается как самая обычная буква. " _питон после слеша в строке при переносе 23145\ 2525 автоматически вставляет \n._ " - что именно куда вставляется в каком случае? Все совсем не так, как тут написано.

Comment: Ну понятно, видимо пре переносе другой механизм работает, раз весь \n убирается.

Comment: \n при переносе никуда не убирается. \n и есть перенос.

Comment: Если бы не убирался, то не исчезал бы при экранировании слешом, а так если написать в строке, то буква остается.

Comment: не исчезал бы откуда при экранировании где? При экранировании чего?